# Passing Model to Controller

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Following is my relevant Code. I get all values as null in my Controller Action.

How to pass Model to Controller?

```
var Settings = [];
Settings.push({
    Server: Server,
    Name: Name,
    Email: Email                    
});

Settings = JSON.stringify({ 'Settings ': Settings });

jq.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Site/insertSettings',
    data: Settings ,
    success: function () {
        ....
    }
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult insertSettings(Settings model)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: use var Settings ={  Server: Server, Name: Name,  mail: Email }

Comment: and also data : JSON.stringify(Settings) for data parameter

Comment: You creating an array of objects, yet your method only expects one object. It should be just `data: { Server: Server, Name: Name, Email: Email },` (assuming those are the 3 properties of `Settings`)

Comment: I would remove the trailing space in `'Settings '`. That's certainly not the root of the problem (see previous comments), but I bet it could fail in some cases.

Comment: For clarity, can you show the code for the `Settings` class in your MVC code please? It's useful to see the properties in that class, in case there are further problems with passing data to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to specify the correct parameter name that the controller is expecting.

Try changing it to this instead:

```
var settings = {Server:Server, Name:Name,Email:Email};
var jsonDataToSend = JSON.stringify({ 'model': settings });
```

Which will contain the model parameter:

```
{"model":{"Server":"Server","Name":"Name","Email":"Email"}}
```

Then:

```
data: jsonDataToSend,
```